# Concatenating values to the same key in an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting data from my database and the data is being retrieved using a while loop.

```
success = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM apidataTwo;"];

while([success next]){

    int first = [success intForColumn:@"id"];
    NSString *id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",first];
    [_tempArray addObject:id];

    NSString *country_name = [success stringForColumn:@"country_name"];
    [_tempArray addObject:country_name];

    NSString *breezometer_description = [success stringForColumn:@"breezometer_description"];
    [_tempArray addObject:breezometer_description];

    NSString *country_description = [success stringForColumn:@"country_description"];
    [_tempArray addObject:country_description];

    NSString *dateString= [success stringForColumn:@"dateString"];
    [_dateSectionArray addObject:dateString];

    [_dataDictionary setObject:_tempArray forKey:dateString];

}
```

Suppose we get the same key in different iterations of the loop. When I pass the array to the `NSMutableDictionary`, the previous values will be replaced and lost.

And if I keep updating the `NSMutableArray`, then the values of a previous key will also be added to a different key.

So in situations like this when we want to concatenate the values to the same key, then what should be our approach.

The dictionary should look like this:

```
{
  2016-10-05" =     (
      5,
      "United States",
      "Fair Air Quality",
      "Good air quality"
  );
  "2016-10-06" =     (
      5,
      "United States",
      "Fair Air Quality",
      "Good air quality"
  );
}
```

Comment: `if (_dataDictionary[dateString]){[(NSMutableArray*)_dataDictionary[dateString] addObjects:theNotIncremetingArray]}else{[_dataDictionary setObject:theNotIncremetingArray forKey:dateString];}` ?

Comment: @Larme The array that I you said to use should be non mutable?

Comment: If you want to `addObjects:` to it, it has to be mutable. I posted what could I understood was your question, because it's quite unclear with the "keep incrementing array".

Comment: @Larme The array in which I am storing the String values from the data base is mutable so after every iteration new values are added and this becomes the value for even those keys which I don't want to.

Comment: At the end, you want all your data in `_dataDictionary`, if there are more for the same day, you put them into the same array for the key `dateString`? The thing, is that's it's unclear why you append `id`, `country_name` etc into a array and not a dictionary.

Comment: @Larme So what I am understanding is that you are creating a new instance of the array if the key is different in the next iteration. And if the key is same then it will append the old array only. Am I right?

Comment: Could you show what should look like at the end `_dataDictionary`, to make things clearer, especially in the case if there are various same object for the same `dateString`?

Comment: @Larme Okay I will edit the question adding that.

Comment: @Larme Edited please check.

Comment: And if in your DB, there are two values of date `2016-10-06`, what happens?

Comment: @Larme That is what I am saying. If I get the same key while iterating through the loop then how can I append the values in the same key?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have figured out the key for this batch of data, try to retrieve an object from the dictionary for that key. If `objectForKey:` returns `nil`, then create a new mutable array. Then set that array as the dictionary's object for that key.

Every new batch of data is then added to the array, not to the dictionary. Here's a sketch of the structure:

```
while( /* processing data */){

    // Collect this batch
    NSArray * entry = ...;
    // Figure out the dictionary key for the batch.
    // (it doesn't have to be a string, this is just for example)
    NSString * key = ...;

    // Try to retrieve the object for that key
    NSMutableArray * entries = _dataDictionary[key];

    // If the result is `nil`, the key is not in the dictionary yet.
    if( !entries ){

        // Create a new mutable array
        entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        // Add that to the dictionary as the value for the given key
        _dataDictionary[key] = entries;
    }

    // Now `entries` is a valid `NSMutableArray`, whether it already
    // existed or was just created. Add this batch.
    [entries addObject:entry];

    // Move on to the next batch.
}
```

Comment: @JoshCorwell Where are we adding the values from entry array to the dictionary key. Should we add the values from the key after the last line?

Comment: At the top you add the individual values to `entry`. Then you add `entry` to `entries`. `entries` is already in the dictionary.

Comment: But where did you add entries to the dictionary. The point where you added is where entries array value is null.

Comment: At line 23 in my example, `[entries addObject:entry];`, `entries` is not `nil`. It's either been retrieved from the dictionary or created inside the if statement.